# printing specific cols in python txt file

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to read in my data stored in a text file containing 25 columns split up by, e.g

```
erd,thr,yui
```

I want to select the 4th and 13th columns and write them to a text file , side by side e.g

```
Mark , baseball
```

I have researched and found code which can do this for a single column but i cant get it working for two , does anyone know how to do this ?

Heres the code I was trying to use

```
col = 2 # third column
filename = '4columns.txt'
third_column = [line[:-1].split('\t')[col] for line in open(filename,
'r')]
```

Comment: So you don't want a simple `awk` command?

Answer (score 4):

Python has a "csv" module (comma-separated values) which you can use for something like this.

```
import csv

with open( "myfile.txt", "r" ) as f:
    for row in csv.reader( f ):
        print row[3], ",", row[13]
```

Comment: brilliant thanks I'll use this , found a few examples but again they were only for one column so didnt think they'd work , thanks